# Return text from a specific td using Python & beautifulsoup4

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am looking to return the text from the "value" class but my problem is, in the table there are multiple td tags with the class "value" and text containing "Module Time: ". So how do you return a result/text when the class name is the same throughout the table, the only difference being the result itself.

HTML:

```
<tr>
<td class='label' style="border-color:#000000;background-color:#FFFFFF;">Module Time:             
</td>
<td class='value' style="border-color:#000000;background-color:#32FFFF;">1.4165606
</td>
</tr>
```

For example, a few lines of code below the snippet above is this:

```
<tr>
<td class='label' style="border-color:#000000;background-color:#FFFFFF;">Module Time:              
</td>
<td class='value' style="border-color:#000000;background-color:#32FFFF;">0.100279
</td>
</tr>
```

So I just want to return the result from the first HTML snippet.

Answer (score 0):

ANSWERED:

I just had to use slices.

```
module_time = soup.find_all("td", text="Module Time:              ")[30].find_next_sibling("td").text
```